# Make Duplicate rejection easier

Tags: feature-request, documentation, hyperlinks

Currently, in order to reject a proposed change as a duplicate, you need to find the URL manually. It is checked to ensure it is a valid Documentation example/topic link:

[image: Duplicate of insert link here]

But my favorite way to get links to Documentation is by using the "Hyperlink" button (<kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd>) to bring up this menu (does not work on Meta, only main SO):

> [image: Insert Docs link]

Can we add this feature to the rejection popup?